# Leaflet.js doesn't render local tiles with PhoneGap

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, leaflet

I'm having a weird issue with leaflet.js + PhoneGap.
I'm displaying a simple map, which tiles have been pre-rendered and thus are loaded locally.

The map renders fine in a local html page, on a local server on my machine, or with Chrome on an Android device (using Prepros remote live refresh).

But, the map is completely blank when running inside a PhoneGap application. It renders inside the Phonegap application only if I use the remote debugging tool jsHybugger (https://www.jshybugger.com/#!/).

Note that I have the same problem using remote tiles (CloudMade).

There must be some network issue I'm not understanding here. Thanks for any clues. Here is my code :

```
var app =
{
    initialize: function() 
    {  
        map = L.map('map').setView([48.86, 2.35], 15);

        var url = './img/tiles/{z}/{x}/{y}.jpg';

        L.tileLayer(url, {
            attribution: 'OSM',
        maxZoom: 15
        }).addTo(map);

    },

};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a local copy of Leaflet instead of a hosted one worked for me.